# PHP Conditions in Javascript code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to add a PHP condition inside some javascript code like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

<?php if (some condition) {
   $('#myID').show();
}

});
</script>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Try it and find out...or view any of the related questions about it

Comment: what are those conditions? Can't you set those conditions outside javascript code, and instead send them as parameters to the javascript function?

Comment: Are you rendering the JavaScript using a PHP script? Then it would be easy. Or do you wanna use a PHP command in JavaScript? Why you can't use a JavaScript if condition?

Comment: Yes another form using [`if/endif`](http://codepad.org/jXvZnwYv).

Comment: +1 to +Aaron W. because I said the same thing in an answer and moderator deleted it

Comment: @shanabus most likely deleted because unless it's a constructive answer it should be in the comments. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php if (some condition): ?>
$('#myID').show();
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put your script inside the PHP file that will be rendering your html and check conditions with PHP.

Example index.php

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
Your webpage content here

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        <?php if(condition) : ?>
            $('#myID').show();
        <?php else : ?>
            $('#mySecondID').show();
        <?php endif; ?>
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If u want to put your JS in a separate file you could do so and initialize some variables inside PHP file that will be rendering your html (for example index.php or whatever template file) the same way as above and this way you can read them from your .js file.

Example:
index.php

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
Your webpage content here
<?php
  $foo = 'foo';
  $bar = 'bar';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var foo = '<?php echo (condition) ? $foo : $bar ?>'; 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

init.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(foo == 'foo')
        $('#myID').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, if wherever you're doing your JavaScript is executed by PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

<?php if(some condition) { ?>
   $('#myID').show();
<?php } ?>

});
</script>
```

If you want to do this dynamically, however, it would be a much nicer and faster solution to use Ajax instead.

Comment: You're saying check the condition with AJAX on page load, right?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: No, I'm not. By "dynamically", I meant "regularly".

Answer (score 2):

Php is going to output something when it is executed on the server side. So when the page load you will not see php code.

You should write your php code such that it will render the JS if condition when the php script is executed.

Something like this.

```
if (something == <?php outputSomeThingToCompare ?>) {
   $('#myID').show();
}
```

Or you can also try this.

```
<?php if(some condition) { ?>
   $('#myID').show();
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

Remember that PHP processes your page **server side**.  So, if you want to change what is in your JavaScript dynamically, then yes, you can do this.

If instead you want PHP to process variables from within JavaScript on the client side, then no, this isn't possible.

Again, the browser has no knowledge of PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but your `<?php` instruction doesn't seem to be closed correctly. Where's the closing `?>` ?

If think you need this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        <?php 
        if (some condition) { 
            echo('$("#myID").show();');
        } 
        ?>
    });                             //$(document).ready
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Depends on file extension.***

If file extension is ***php*** (*or some other you might have put together to run php code using .htaccss rules or apache config*) it is fine not otherwise.

Comment: That is not always true, you can easily configure your server to parse `php` in with file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just echo out the JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

<?php if (some condition) {
   echo("$('#myID').show();");
}?>

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because JavaScript has been compiled on the client side however php works over the server. You can do this by changing it to this ...

```
$string  = '<script>
$(document).ready(function() {';
if (some condition) {
$string .= '$('#myID').show();';
$string .= '}

});
</script>';';
```

Please concat code if error occures.